# Material-UI Slider with discreet values only?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use Slider as a selector instead of a whole bunch of radio buttons. It just looks cleaner.
I've got it working nicely, but the problem is that it always assumes I'm selecting on some kind of scale. If I pick a value in the middle, it highlights everything from the start, up to my selection point.  Problem is, each of my values are individual and not part of some increasing scale (i.e. imagine if the selection options were apple, banana, orange).

At the following link, MUI's slider is like example #1. I need it to be like example #4.
http://react-component.github.io/slider/examples/marks.html

Is it possible? Or do I just need to use the slider from this other lib?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an example of how to do this with two key customizations:

1. Hide the track. The full bar representing the slider is called the "rail". The active/selected portion of the rail is called the "track".
2. Style active marks the same as inactive marks. The [default styling](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.3.1/packages/material-ui/src/Slider/Slider.js#L255) lightens the marks that are within the track so that they are still visible, but this is undesirable if the track is not being displayed since it makes the marks more difficult to see.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: 300 + 24 * 2,
    padding: 24
  },
  margin: {
    height: theme.spacing(3)
  }
}));

const NoTrackSlider = withStyles({
  track: {
    display: "none"
  },
  markActive: {
    backgroundColor: "currentColor"
  }
})(Slider);

export default function CustomizedSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.margin} />
      <Typography gutterBottom>No Track</Typography>
      <NoTrackSlider step={10} valueLabelDisplay="on" marks defaultValue={30} />
      <div className={classes.margin} />
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Slider no track]

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't expect it would be so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been answered but I faced a similar problem. The slider API provides a way of restricting values to your discrete marks by setting step to null.

`step={null}`

https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#restricted-values

I had numbers on a number scale that stepped up by 5 but I needed it to skip 5. So I set individual marks excluding 5 and it worked like a charm. Only problem is that visually it still maintains the scale with the spacing of the marks.